# Dismiss View Controller Doesn't Working in Helper Class Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a helper class as written below:

```
class Helper {
   static func handleTokenInvalid() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIViewController().dismiss()
        }
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    func dismiss() {
        let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        root?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)    }
}
```

I want to dismiss all the view controller that open and back to root of the apps.  However it doesn't work. If I do the same in ordinary view controller is works. Anyone know the solution? Thank you!

Edit:
I already tried this too, but it said that found nil when wrapping optional value.

```
func dismiss() {
        self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days finding the right way to dismiss my controller and couldn't find any because I think Xcode find that my current controller is nil. Instead, I use this:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "DashboardPreLogin", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarPreLoginViewController")

let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDel.window?.rootViewController = nil
appDel.window?.rootViewController = viewController
UIView.transition(with: appDel.window!, duration: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {() -> Void in appDel.window?.rootViewController = viewController}, completion: nil)
```

This will dismissing view controller and replace with new controller.

Answer (score 2):

All you are doing by this

```
UIViewController().dismiss
```

Is creating a new view controller and dismissing it.
You have to call dismiss on the actually presented View controller instance.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: If this does not work: self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
You are probably pushing view controllers (Via navigation controller) and this should work: self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

Comment: I've tried this too but it doesn't work. Is there any problem in storyboard?

Comment: It's not answering, I found alternative that I already answer in this question. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

You can you use this anywhere on your Helper class

```
if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController() {
   topController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: are you seen this point `all the view controller that open and back to root of the apps`

Comment: Please check what answer is provided below (MCMatan), that suits more as per the code provided by Firda

Comment: @Sahzaib Qureshi I've done this and still not going back to the root

Answer (score 0):

You can change the rootViewController,

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = yourController
```

Comment: it give me error Cannot assign value of type 'yourController.Type' to type 'UIViewController?'

Comment: YourController it's just an example word, instead of that replace your controller instance there.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is better solution without dismissing root view controller of current application's window.

Add completion handler to your method and when you call it from inside of your controller, in closure declare that after completion will be called, you need to dismiss `self` (if you're pushing your controller via `UINavigationController`, just pop it)

```
static func handleTokenInvalid(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion()
    }
}
```

Then in controller call your method with completion handler

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func call() {
        Helper.handleTokenInvalid { // this is called when you call `completion` from `handleTokenInvalid`
            self.dismiss(animated: true)
            //self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have many controller in my app so I want to avoid change in every controller. Is it possible to dismiss in helper class?